# Dataframe rolling mean, replaces column, how do I keep the original column and add the rolling mean as a new column?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, mean, rolling-computation

I have a DF:

```
  tbname    stat_day    count
0    calc_10  2020-05-01        0
1    calc_10  2020-05-02        0
2    calc_10  2020-05-03        0
<snip>
49   calc_10  2020-06-19      361
50   calc_10  2020-06-20      506
51   calc_10  2020-06-21        0
52   calc_10  2020-06-22        0
53   calc_12  2020-05-01        0
54   calc_12  2020-05-02        0
<snip>
73   calc_12  2020-05-21        0
74   calc_12  2020-05-22        0
75   calc_12  2020-05-23        0
<snip>
```

I then group it and get a rolling mean:

```
gp=df_tsd.groupby(['tbname'])
df_gp=gp.rolling(30,on='stat_day').mean()
```

I'd like to keep the count column and add a RMA column, but the rolling().mean() replaces the count column with the rolling value:

```
               stat_day          count
tbname                                
calc_10 0    2020-05-01            NaN
        1    2020-05-02            NaN
        2    2020-05-03            NaN
<snip>        41   2020-06-11       0.000000
        42   2020-06-12     249.533333
        43   2020-06-13     777.333333
        44   2020-06-14    1310.333333
        45   2020-06-15    1841.700000
        46   2020-06-16    2235.933333
        47   2020-06-17    2259.933333
        48   2020-06-18    2283.200000
        49   2020-06-19    2295.233333
        50   2020-06-20    2312.100000
        51   2020-06-21    2312.100000
        52   2020-06-22    2312.100000
```

Update:
Your code works! (naturally), I added some tweaks:

```
df_tsd['RDA']=df_tsd.groupby('tbname')['count'].transform(lambda x: x.rolling(7).mean())
print(df_tsd.groupby('tbname').tail(30).round({'RDA':0}).to_string(index=False))
```

And this is the output:

```
  tbname    stat_day  count     RDA
 calc_10  2020-05-24      0     0.0
 calc_10  2020-05-25      0     0.0
 calc_10  2020-05-26      0     0.0
 calc_10  2020-05-27      0     0.0
 calc_10  2020-05-28      0     0.0
 calc_10  2020-05-29      0     0.0
 calc_10  2020-05-30      0     0.0
<snip>
 calc_10  2020-06-12   7486  1069.0
 calc_10  2020-06-13  15834  3331.0
 calc_10  2020-06-14  15990  5616.0
 calc_10  2020-06-15  15941  7893.0
 calc_10  2020-06-16  11827  9583.0
 calc_10  2020-06-17    720  9685.0
 <snip>
calc_12  2020-06-02   1959   280.0
 calc_12  2020-06-03   1582   506.0
 calc_12  2020-06-04      0   506.0
```

My code (which doesn't quite work) ends up without the new rolling column, but the output is neat, note the control break on the tbname:

```
              stat_day   count
tbname                        
calc_10 23  2020-05-24     0.0
        24  2020-05-25     0.0
        25  2020-05-26     0.0
        26  2020-05-27     0.0
<snip>
calc_12 70  2020-05-18     0.0
        71  2020-05-19     0.0
        72  2020-05-20     0.0
<snip>
        88  2020-06-05   506.0
        89  2020-06-06   506.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do it in two steps.  You can use the `transform` function to do it in one line and just add the moving average column to your base dataframe.

I changed your data a bit to make an example.  See below for base data, the command, and the output that I think you're looking for.  I used a 3 day moving average to make it easier to display.

Then if you want to display it with the grouping, do what you originally did, but with a 1-day moving window.

```
>>> df
     tbname     statday  count
0   calc_10  2020-05-01      1
1   calc_10  2020-05-02      2
2   calc_10  2020-05-03      3
3   calc_10  2020-05-04      4
4   calc_10  2020-05-05      5
5   calc_10  2020-05-06      6
6   calc_10  2020-05-07      7
7   calc_10  2020-05-08      8
8   Calc_11  2020-05-01      1
9   Calc_11  2020-05-02      2
10  Calc_11  2020-05-03      3
11  Calc_11  2020-05-04      4
12  Calc_11  2020-05-05      5
13  Calc_11  2020-05-06      6
14  Calc_11  2020-05-07      7
15  Calc_12  2020-05-01      1
16  Calc_12  2020-05-02      2
17  Calc_12  2020-05-03      3
18  Calc_12  2020-05-04      4
19  Calc_12  2020-05-05      5
20  Calc_12  2020-05-06      6
21  Calc_12  2020-05-07      7
22  Calc_12  2020-05-08      8
23  Calc_12  2020-05-09      9
>>> df['ma'] = df.groupby('tbname')['count'].transform(lambda x: x.rolling(3).mean())
>>> df
     tbname     statday  count   ma
0   calc_10  2020-05-01      1  NaN
1   calc_10  2020-05-02      2  NaN
2   calc_10  2020-05-03      3  2.0
3   calc_10  2020-05-04      4  3.0
4   calc_10  2020-05-05      5  4.0
5   calc_10  2020-05-06      6  5.0
6   calc_10  2020-05-07      7  6.0
7   calc_10  2020-05-08      8  7.0
8   Calc_11  2020-05-01      1  NaN
9   Calc_11  2020-05-02      2  NaN
10  Calc_11  2020-05-03      3  2.0
11  Calc_11  2020-05-04      4  3.0
12  Calc_11  2020-05-05      5  4.0
13  Calc_11  2020-05-06      6  5.0
14  Calc_11  2020-05-07      7  6.0
15  Calc_12  2020-05-01      1  NaN
16  Calc_12  2020-05-02      2  NaN
17  Calc_12  2020-05-03      3  2.0
18  Calc_12  2020-05-04      4  3.0
19  Calc_12  2020-05-05      5  4.0
20  Calc_12  2020-05-06      6  5.0
21  Calc_12  2020-05-07      7  6.0
22  Calc_12  2020-05-08      8  7.0
23  Calc_12  2020-05-09      9  8.0
>>> dfgp=df.groupby(['tbname'])
>>> df_gp=gp.rolling(1,on='statday').mean()
>>> df_gp
               statday  count   ma
tbname                            
Calc_11 8   2020-05-01    1.0  NaN
        9   2020-05-02    2.0  NaN
        10  2020-05-03    3.0  2.0
        11  2020-05-04    4.0  3.0
        12  2020-05-05    5.0  4.0
        13  2020-05-06    6.0  5.0
        14  2020-05-07    7.0  6.0
Calc_12 15  2020-05-01    1.0  NaN
        16  2020-05-02    2.0  NaN
        17  2020-05-03    3.0  2.0
        18  2020-05-04    4.0  3.0
        19  2020-05-05    5.0  4.0
        20  2020-05-06    6.0  5.0
        21  2020-05-07    7.0  6.0
        22  2020-05-08    8.0  7.0
        23  2020-05-09    9.0  8.0
calc_10 0   2020-05-01    1.0  NaN
        1   2020-05-02    2.0  NaN
        2   2020-05-03    3.0  2.0
        3   2020-05-04    4.0  3.0
        4   2020-05-05    5.0  4.0
        5   2020-05-06    6.0  5.0
        6   2020-05-07    7.0  6.0
        7   2020-05-08    8.0  7.0
```

Comment: Oh my, transform and lambda! Let me give it a whirl. Thanks!

Comment: I added and update above, thanks for your help, but I do like how my example breaks the output by tbname. Being a complete novice to Pandas, I can't explain that,... any thoughts?

Comment: Oh, I see, you want the single line output in tbname.  Just take the df in my example and then do what you did: groupby and then the rolling, using a 1 day window.  I'll add it to my answer

Comment: Thanks very much, I appreciate the help. I have much to learn, lol!

Comment: @PhilippeGodfrin no problem.  If you find an answer useful, it' generally good practice to upvote it using the arrows to the left of the answer :)